# Can I add a metadata to a source file in eclipse on save/commit/upload?

Tags: eclipse, git, version-control

At work we use the svn $Id$-Property to track the most recent revision in our source files (particularily JavaScript files) on commit.

For smaller freelance projects at home (Web or Java) I use eclipse and local git version tracking.

I would love to add meta-data such as a timestamp or last saved revision to my source files. It doesn't matter much to me, whether the data would be added on saving, commiting or uploading a file.

A token replace method like svns $Id$ would be best, but I'm open to any other method.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62264/dealing-with-svn-keyword-expansion-with-git-svn

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Git book's "Git attributes"](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes) section, the part speaking about custom clean/smudge filters is probably something you will find useful!