# git-svn loses $Id$ comments in java files

Tags: git, svn, migration, comments

I'm trying to migrate from svn to git using git-svn package. All is fine, except one thing. After I launch git svn clone command, repository converts successfully, but all comments like this:

```
 * @version     $Id: source.java date time author name $
```

Are immediately converted to comments like this:

```
* @version     $Id$
```

Is there a way to avoid this? Here is the full command that I use:

```
git svn clone http://svn.server/svn/repository/folder_in_root --preserve-empty-dirs -A committers.txt --trunk=. new_folder
```

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#_keyword_expansion

Comment: https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#Does_Git_have_keyword_expansion.3F

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62264/dealing-with-svn-keyword-expansion-with-git-svn

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**

No, Git doesn't have keyword-substitution (contrary to SVN), and because it's pure client-side thing in SVN, you can do nothing on server

**Longer answer**

You can emulate this (somehow) with smudge|clean filters in Git, but:

1. You'll have to rewrite all (?) keywords for Git
2. Old keywords in old commits, thus, will *not be* expanded on checkout anyway

Comment: Did not understood answer till the end. No, this means I cannot stop git to rewrite comments in source files? This happens before I'm committing anything to new git repository. I don't need git to use comments in source code. I, just, need to stop git changing Java source code files.

Answer (score 0):

git is not changing `$Id: source.java date time author name $` into `$Id$`. In fact it's the very opposite: it's failing to change `$Id$` into `$Id: source.java date time author name $` because [git doesn't support keyword expansion](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#Does_Git_have_keyword_expansion.3F) out of the box. In Subversion, the feature works by storing the raw unexpanded keyword in the repository (`$Id$`) and expanding it when you check out a working copy.