# How to determine files that are subjected to filter via gitattributes when filter is executed?

Tags: ruby, git, gitattributes

I have bunch of ruby scripts in a git repository and it seems to be really hard to enforce people to write properly indented code.

I also have a small ruby script that formats to code to specific standard and now i would like to run that as a a filter script so that junk wont get committed into repository.

```
echo "*.rb filter=rubyfilter" > .gitattributes
echo "[filter \"rubyfilter\"]" >> .git/config
echo "    clean = /home/rasjani/bin/rbeauty" >> .git/config
echo "    smudge = /home/rasjani/bin/rbeauty" >> .git/config
```

does the dirty trick git side but the ruby script should then process the files affected:

how / where do i look those up from ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the [GitPro Book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes)

> Git applies those settings only for a subdirectory or subset of files. These path-specific settings are called Git attributes and are set either in a .gitattributes file in one of your directories

The [`git attributes`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) man page mentions:

> - Upon checkout, when the smudge command is specified, the command is fed the blob object from its standard input, and its standard output is used to update the worktree file.
> - Similarly, the clean command is used to convert the contents of worktree file upon checkin.

[image]

So your script will process each `*.rb` files (in the directory and subdirectories where the `.gitattributes` file is located) on checkout and commit.

See this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316677/can-git-automatically-switch-between-spaces-and-tabs/2316728#2316728) for a concrete example.
You can test your own setup with a:

```
git checkout --force
```

Note: as mentioned in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059326/git-equivalent-of-subversions-url-keyword-expansion/2059393#2059393), `smudge` and `clean` scripts can only modify the *content* of a file, without knowing *what exact file* they are processing.

Comment: Doesnt really answer the question as i was really looking a way to actually get the filenames but i'll accept this anyway since there has been no other answers.

Comment: @rasjani: "get the filename", that is precisely why I have linked to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059326/git-equivalent-of-subversions-url-keyword-expansion/2059393#2059393: a filter driver can only get the *content* of a file, not its filename. It will be called during the checkout step and will in effect "process the files affected".

Comment: yes, fully understand this, and thats why i accepted the answer. But the spirit of the question was mainly about how to get the filenames, not about the content so any alternative way to archive what i asked would have been more than fine.

Comment: @rasjani: I have not tested it but I wonder if, after a smudge script, you can diff the working tree with HEAD and find that way all those files that has been processed.