# Want git post receive hook to make new commit and push

Tags: git, push, git-post-receive

I would like my post-receive hook to be responsible for updating a version file in the repo
itself, under certain conditions. So, suppose I have a file version.txt in my repository,
I would like the post receive hook to update a version string inside version.txt.

That would mean another push to the repo. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rather not try to make any further commit/push, but use a [filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316677/can-git-automatically-switch-between-spaces-and-tabs/2316728#2316728) in order, on checkout/update to be able to generate the right content for that `version.txt` file (i.e. with the right version string inside)

[image]

The `smudge` script, if it is able to recognized the content of a `version.txt` file (i.e. it [**won't** have the name/path of said file as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059326/git-equivalent-of-subversions-url-keyword-expansion/2059393#2059393)), would replace a template section of that file with the right information.

Comment: @VonC Is it possible to have this in the receiving repository? Since the condition for updating version.txt might only be applicable in the central / receiving repo and filter drivers are only applicable while committing ( and checking out )from local repo right?

Comment: @manojolds: the idea is to *never* commit a file with that information, but to commit the script able to generate the right content whenever a downstream repo will need it. A filter driver is a declaration in a `.gitattributes` file, which can be cloned/propagated amongst repo. The fact that they aren't activated on the central repo (because you only push to those) but would be on a local repo don't change the fact that no extra commit is necessary on the central repo: you will generate the right content when and where you will actually need it.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks, VonC. .gitattributes seems perfect for this.

Comment: Pushing a second time felt a little "odd hack".

Comment: One question: smudge/clean scripts are set in the .config file. I would like all of the developers to use these scripts. If I modify the .config file in the central repo, how can everyone make sure their .config files match?

Comment: @Jacko: well, the scripts aren't declared in files that are pushed/fetched, for security reason and for distributed reason (the path to said scripts might not make sense from one repo environment to another). The `.config` file from the central repo has no meaning/bearing for all the downstream (clients) repos. A system config file could have a global effect if all users are on the same server where Git is installed, but that isn't a very "decentralized" setup then.

Comment: Thanks. In the end, I decided to move the logic to the build script. So, the build script will update the version, based on the checkin history.

Comment: @Jacko: good call, this is an information more needed in RM (Release Management) than SCM (Software Configuration Management), so your move makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

You can have a working directory of your repo on your server. In the post-receive, git pull on the working directory, update the version.txt as needed and commit and push. This will trigger the post-receive one more time, so be careful about how you are doing your conditional update, otherwise it will go into a cycle.

```
#!/bin/sh
unset GIT_DIR
cd /path/to/repo.wd
git pull
echo "new content" > version.txt
git add version.txt
git commit -m "updating version.txt"
git push origin master
```