# How to keep different content of one file in my local and github repository?

Tags: git, github

I have a database.php. I want to keep it in my github repository without any sensitive information.

First I pushed to my repository without any sensitive info.

Now I added my database info so that I can use it locally.

I added to .gitignore. And I did rm --cached database.php. But it deleted the database.php from my github repository after a push.

How can I keep different content in my local and github repository?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make 2 different files one actual `database.php` and one `database.php.example` or something like that and then add database.php to `.gitignore`

Comment: +1: The answer is often to avoid the problem! In these situations, with data files containing sensitive information, essentially *every* developer and user will end up putting sensitive information in there. The developers won't want to commit those changes, and the users won't want them to be overwritten if they update, so it's definitely good to have the template in a separate file.

Comment: Another suggestion is to make your app handle the missing file gracefully by generating a default one.  This way a new developer doesn't have to go in and copy the example file over, things just work out of the box.  If they already have the file, it's not overwritten.

Comment: That  is also a nice technique but the problem with that is that you make it easy to use default configurations which most of the time means you make it easier for someone to make mistakes or setup a vulnerable website :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use a **[filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316677/can-git-automatically-switch-between-spaces-and-tabs/2316728#2316728)** able to:

[image: filter driver]

- on checkout, in the `smudge` script, **[detect the *content*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059326/git-equivalent-of-subversions-url-keyword-expansion/2059393#2059393)** (those 'filter driver' scripts don't have the name of the files they are filtering) of a `database.template`
- generate the private, always ignored, `database.php`, based on the values of a:

  - `database.private.value` file (also always ignored)
  - or, if `database.private.value` isn't found (which is the case for your user cloning your repo), a `database.public.value` file (which is pushed to the remote repo)
- no need to do anything on the commit (script `clean`) step.