# How to merge the remote branch and ignore the config setting?

Tags: git, github

I working on a cms project and using a open source cms that hosted on github , how can I fetch the latest commit remotely to my working copy without overwrite some of my local setting ? example my database setting etc ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always recommend a [**filter driver**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316677/can-git-automatically-switch-between-spaces-and-tabs/2316728#2316728) with:

[image]

- a template for those setting files (versioned in Git)
- some files with the right values depending on the environment
- a script able to build the actual setting files (as a 'smudge' script)

See "[How to keep different content of one file in my local and github repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031800/how-to-keep-different-content-of-one-file-in-my-local-and-github-repository/6031981#6031981)" for more details.

Comment: but i got no control to setup the template file ? since the cms is clone over from github ?

Comment: @Knight: the template and value files are additional files you can add to the repo. You need to have a script able to detect the current environment in which the repo is cloned in order to build the right setting files.

Answer (score 1):

It's usually best to remove those files from the repo and add them to your .gitignore.  You can then make the app gracefully handle missing configs by generating a default file.  Failing that, you can provide an "example" config file for the user to copy and edit.