# git version control for multiple modules in product

Tags: git, version-control, version

We have a product with a standard code base. Product has several modules. This code is taken as a base code and different teams develop on it for Sales, Road map, multiple implementation with customer specific customisations, bug fixes etc..

In each set up, all the modules may or may not be present. We are trying to implement the version control using GIT. How to manage module wise version control so that we can create module wise patches and we can maintain the patches module wise.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, modules are managed in their own git repo, and included in the main project git repo as **[submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules)**.

That allows for the project to record the exact versions of each modules used at any point in the history of said project.

Note that some of the variations can also be managed through **[content filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6236130/6309)**, as in "[Structure in git with multiple websites](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13862086/6309)". That avoids creating more repos or even more branches in a repo than necessary.
the idea is to detect the right environment on checkout, and automatically filter/create the right files for that environment.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. But this will create huge number of git repo, since modules and number of customers are large. Also many customers with a same modules are not on a same version.

Comment: @Rajendra no: each module can manage slight variation in branches (like one per client). You don't have to create that many repos.

Comment: @Rajendra I have also edited the answer to add the other mechanism: content filer driver.

Comment: thanks.. this seems to be interesting. i will check.