# Modify file before commit with pre-commit hook

Tags: git, githooks, pre-commit

I am trying to write a pre-commit hook that modify a line in my code but I do not know even from where to start.

The problem is:

I have a `KEY`

```
public static final String APP_KEY = ""; //DELETE THE KEY BEFORE COMMIT!!!
```

In order to avoid publishing the KEY to the repository I've think maybe git hooks are the thing we need instead of delete the key manually. I've take a look at [Customizing git hooks](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) but I do not know how to write the hook.

Is there a way to before commit the changes, delete the KEy and after the commit write the key again?

Comment: Why not just store the key in a separate file, and then gitignore that file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That could be done with a **[content filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6236130/6309)**:

- a `clean` script which would remove the key on checking,
- a `smudge` script which would add it back on checkout.

[image: smudge]

<sup>(image from "[Customizing Git Attributes](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes)" from the [Git Book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/))</sup>

See an example of how those filters are declared in "[Can git automatically switch between spaces and tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2316728/6309)".

### Caveat:

As noted by [Juan Alonso](https://stackoverflow.com/users/722456/juan-alonso) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25217347/modify-file-before-commit-with-pre-commit-hook/25217391#comment127195719_25217391):

> I've had nothing but trouble with the clean/smudge scripts for a similar use-case, depending on the file contents unattended runs of `git add -A` would or wouldn't run the filter (as opposed to always working when calling `git` in attended mode).
>
> So I ended up going with a **pre-commit hook**.

Comment: Um, Thanks I will try to write a simple script.

Comment: @algui91 yes, the idea is to be able to associate that script to a single file, or type of files, through the `.gitattributes` `filter` command.

Comment: this is lame. It's great to show a diagram but all this does is leave us with more questions than answers. Why not extend this with example code.

Comment: @JohnRiselvato https://stackoverflow.com/a/2316728/6309 is (mentioned in the answer) suppose to illustrate an example of a clean/smudge script declared as content filter driver. don't hesitate to ask a new question (with a link back to this answer) in order to get additional information.

Comment: I've had nothing but trouble with the clean/smudge scripts for a similar use-case, depending on the file contents unattended runs of git add -A would or wouldn't run the filter (as opposed to always working when calling git in attended mode) so I ended up going with a pre-commit hook.

Comment: @JuanAlonso good point. That might be more reliable indeed.