# How to prevent lines from being deleted after merging

Tags: git, merge, patch

Is there a way to prevent the lines to be removed during the merging and make them available in the produced output (in a distinguishable form)?

Ideally, I want to keep lines "to be removed" as commented.

But it would be totally ok if there is a way to force merge to behave as it is a conflict situation (even if there are no conflicts at all), in order to produce the source with `<<<<<<<` `=======` `>>>>>>>` markers in it.

I've tried to use hunk by hunk patching, using `git add -p` and then choosing "e" option for editing. But seems that it doesn't allow line's content to be edited.

Comment: Playing the devil's advocate, do you _really_ want all that stuff in there as comments?  Most IDEs (e.g. IntelliJ) with Git integration make it very easy to visually trace back the history of a file, find removed content, etc.  I'd rather rely on that then maintaining void information in my source files.

Comment: I agree, it's not something I want to do all the time. It's just an exceptional case.

Comment: There is a way to force Git to never do an auto complete of a merge on a file.  If you poke around SO, you will find it.  If I recall correctly, it is fairly draconian.

Comment: You need to provide some actual examples, because I do not understand exactly what you want here.

Comment: From my guessing, it sounds like you want to keep (parts of) undo of a merge for some time. Maybe you can make this by merging normally, running `git diff $AFTER_MERGE $BEFORE_MERGE | git apply -; git add -p; git commit -m "=== merge undo ==="`. Keeping the undo information in a `distinguishable form` is easy when you [mark the commits specially](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26700877/23118) instead of trying to do something with the code (although you might want to comment it).

Comment: Although I have to say keeping commented code around in the source is a horrible anti-pattern that you should refrain from performing.