# What is best practice for keeping secrets out of a git repository?

Tags: git, version-control, versioning

**Problem**

Consider this file tree as my development repository.

```
 - foo/
   - .git/
     - [...]
   - bar/
     - backupclient.py
   - supersecretstoragecredentials.ini
```

For development, `supersecretstoragecredentials.ini` needs to be filled in with valid credentials - while I still have to keep a clean version of it in the repository so that other users can easily set their credentials.

**Possible solutions**

1. `.gitignore` `supersecretstoragecredentials.ini` and create a `supersecretstoragecredentials.ini-example`,

   1. instruct the user to copy `supersecretstoragecredentials.ini-example` to `supersecretstoragecredentials.ini`.
2. Add an overriding config file location in `backup.py` which is ignored by git, *e.g.* `supersecretstoragecredentials_local.ini`.

*As [kan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8309428/202522) pointed out, these two solutions are similar but not entirely the same, workflow-wise.*

are there any other alternatives? Does `git` possess some kind of functionality to assist with this kind issues?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check in the supersecretstoragecredentials.ini file with some placeholder values and then

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged supersecretstoragecredentials.ini
```

Git will not track future changes to this file.

You can reset this using

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged supersecretstoragecredentials.ini
```

Comment: The only problem with this solutions is that a `git pull` by another user will create merge conflicts. Still, it's a great solution as long as your consumer base is limited.

Comment: @jwandborg good point to note! only proposed this solution since this file is used to store local credentials..

Answer (score 5):

What you are describing in Option 1 is basically covered by the `smudge` step of a content [filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7148518/when-a-commit-to-revision-control-requires-a-developer-to-change-their-own-confi/7148640#7148640).

[image: filter driver]

You have the two options presented in the "[How to work on a drop-in library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7349802/how-to-work-on-a-drop-in-library/7350745#7350745)" question.

the smudge script would take your `supersecretstoragecredentials.ini-example` (versioned), copy it as a `supersecretstoragecredentials.ini` (*not* versioned, ignored by Git), and fill its values from another source.

But beside the technical aspect of how you will implement your policy, the main measure is to make sure your secret values aren't store in a Git repo at all, but are comming from another referential.

Answer (score 3):

I use your solution (your two solutions are the same, only file names differ). Do you have any issues with it? What kind of functionality would you expect?

Also, there is a more interesting solution

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged supersecretstoragecredentials.ini
```

Hopefully it's what you want. However it would fail if the upstream changes the file and you are pulling the change (not completely sure is it good or bad).

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, after having tried all options listed in your question and in the answers so far, your #2 option has proven the simplest and cleanest. It solves the problem reliably, with the least magic, and is easiest to understand. It is boring in the best way.

Comment: And with that, the solution mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/a/8309450/202522 is the easiest and best choice IMO.

Comment: No, you want plain `.gitingore` for the `_local.ini` file.

Answer (score 1):

Something that I am trialling at the moment is git-secrets.

https://github.com/awslabs/git-secrets

It hooks into the git commit process and checks for patterns that look like credentials that should not be checked in.

You have to ensure that it is installed on each developer's system and configured for each git repository.  This can be achieved easily enough if you integrate a check into the build process.