# Different versions of the same configuration file in different branches

Tags: git, dotcloud

We are using dotCloud, a virtual host, to run some of our apps.  dotCloud deploys apps directly from a git repo, and reads a configuration file called dotcloud.yml from that repo to configure and run the stack.

We have two branches (one production, one staging) that are part of the same repo, and these push to separate dotCloud instances.  There is a minor difference in the dotcloud.yml file to run each of these instances.

What is the best way to manage this dotcloud.yml file?  Currently we simply make sure we're making sure the dotcloud.yml is correct on each branch, but it constantly gets overwritten as we merge changes from staging to master.

Comment: Can you describe this "minor difference" in `dotcloud.yml` between your production and staging branches?

Comment: I'm guessing environment variables and such.

Answer (score 1):

You could:

- version a `dotcloud.yml.template`
- version a `dotcloud.yml.value.prod` and a `dotcloud.yml.value.staging` with the pertinent values for each environment.
- version a smudge script in charge of building the right `dotcloud.ym`l file (which wouldn't be versioned anymore) depending on dotCloud instance.

You would declare that smudge script as a [filter content driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031800/how-to-keep-different-content-of-one-file-in-my-local-and-github-repository/6031981#6031981) in a (also versioned) [`.gitattribute` file](http://schacon.github.com/git/gitattributes.html):

[image: filter driver]

On any git checkout, the smudge script will be called and, if it recognized the `dotcloud.yml.template` content, will build the right `dotcloud.yml` file.

Answer (score 1):

You could:

- add `dotcloud.yml` to `.gitignore`, have two separate files for staging and production (e.g. `dotcloud.yml.staging` and `dotcloud.yml.production`), both present in your git repository, setup a symlink `dotcloud.yml → dotcloud.yml.production`, and push with `dotcloud push --rsync` (the `--rsync` flag will override the push mechanism detection, and the rsync mechanism will kick in, instead of the git mechanism);
- use the same `dotcloud.yml` file, but rely on a different mechanism (e.g. `dotcloud var` or a `postinstall` script) to switch between the production and staging behaviors.

Comment: Please note that the new (0.9) dotcloud cli tool doesn't have the `--all` flag for `dotcloud push` so this answer won't work.

Comment: You're right; it has been changed to --rsync. I updated my answer. Thank you!