# codenvy: How to create a persistent file?

Tags: git, cloud, codenvy

I'm learning codenvy.io, and have most of my code in git. This part works well with projects.

However, the code has a secrets file, which is not in git, but is created on the individual computers that you are running the code on. Using codenvy, this file is removed everytime I restart my workplace.

Is there a way to tag this file as "persistent", even though it cannot be in git?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, codenvy.io restore and backup processes respect .gitignore. You may however, put your sensitive files outside /projects and they will be persisted when a workspace is snapshotted.

Answer (score 1):

You could add to your git repo a  smudge script as a [filter content driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031800/how-to-keep-different-content-of-one-file-in-my-local-and-github-repository/6031981#6031981) in a (also versioned) [`.gitattribute` file](http://schacon.github.com/git/gitattributes.html):

[image: filter driver]

On any git checkout, the smudge script will be called and can fetch your secret file (provided it can access the file on the individual computer, or provided that file is stored in a shared accessible path somehow), and create it in your working tree (as a file ignored by the `.gitignore`)