# Can I include other .gitignore file in a .gitignore file? (like #include in c-like languages)

Tags: git, gitignore

I have some files like `vim.gitignore`, `SVN.gitignore` and `CVS.gitignore` (spread around on my hard disk).

Can I simply include these gitignore files in a `.gitignore` file in a new Git project?

**Edit**: I have a global ignore file already.
I just want to ignore different files in different types of projects, is this possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could:

- Have a template repo with:

  - those `xxx.gitignore` files in it:
  - a `.gitignore` file with "`xxx-gitignore-xxx`" in it (in other word, with a *content* you can easily identify
  - a [`.gitattribute` filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316677/can-git-automatically-switch-between-spaces-and-tabs/2316728#2316728)

(for each new repo, you clone it and can start with those files already there.
Then you remove the remote '`origin`', or replace it by whatever remote repo you want to push to)

[image: smudge content filter]
<sup>(image shown in "[Customizing Git - Git Attributes](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#_keyword_expansion)", from "[Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/)")</sup>

On any checkout of your repo, the filter driver will, through the `smudge` script:

- recognize the *content* of the `.gitignore` file
- check if the `xxx.gitignore` content isn't already there (by looking for a specific string which only those files have)
- if their content isn't there, it will append the content of those `xxx.gitignore` files
- if the content is already up-to-date, it wouldn't modify the `.gitignore`.

Note that having a *identifiable content* is key here, since a [filter driver script doesn't have the name/path of the file it filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059326/git-equivalent-of-subversions-url-keyword-expansion/2059393#2059393).

It is a bit convoluted, but seems to be the only way to implement the "include" feature you want.

Comment: Good use of attributes, wouldn't have thought of it, but wish it wasn't there. Unnecessary complexity IMO.

Comment: @manojlds: "Unnecessary complexity"? I agree! But it is a possible implementation...

Comment: It's too complex. any other idea? please

Comment: This post contains a dead image link. It's definitely not getting any easier to understand.

Comment: @mbomb007  I have restored the image link, with additional references.

Answer (score 7):

The closes you will get is the global ignore file:

```
git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore
```

which is of course like having a `.gitignore` in the repo, but applicable to all repos on your system ( and not propagated to external clones.)

Comment: thanks! But I have global ignore file already. I just want to ignore different files in different type of project, could be possible?

Answer (score 5):

I run the a project that hosts the largest amount of gitignore templates and it's extremely easy to use.

- You can use the web to generate a template at https://gitignore.io
- You can install gitignore [via command line](https://www.gitignore.io/docs#-install-command-line-linux) to type

  ```
  gi cvs,vim,svn
  ```

  output: https://www.gitignore.io/api/cvs,vim,svn
- You can also update your existing templates using this url:
  https://www.gitignore.io/?templates=cvs,vim,svn
- And finally, you can contribute to the list of templates which merges [@github/gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore) and over 100 other community templates to create the largest repository of templates at: https://github.com/dvcs/gitignore

This doesn't allow anyone to include sub-templates, but it does generate one large template from individual git templates.

Comment: This answer came much later than others, but deserves much more attention.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the [@slidewave/gitignore-include NPM package](https://github.com/SlideWave/gitignore-include) to accomplish the task.

Example:

```
## <include href="path/to/vim.gitignore">
## </include>
## <include href="path/to/SVN.gitignore">
## </include>
## <include href="path/to/CVS.gitignore">
## </include>
## <include href="https://github.com/github/gitignore/raw/main/Global/macOS.gitignore">
## </include>
## <include href="https://github.com/github/gitignore/raw/main/Global/VisualStudioCode.gitignore">
## </include>

# Any local overrides go here.
```

Then either

1. execute `npx -p @slidewave/gitignore-include giismudge .gitignore` to bring everything together,
2. hook up the git hooks to smudge your ignore files on commit, or
3. set up a `.gitattribute` filter driver as noted in [VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7005830/7363787) but using `giismudge` to do the work.

Caveat: anyone, including you, who needs to re-smudge the ignore files will need to have the same source files at the same paths in order to make this work. So I recommend placing your source gitignore files into a public repository and using the raw URLs to them similar to what I showed for the macOS and VSCode include directives.

Note that I'm the author of the tool, so I'm a bit biased and am responding as a form of advertising the tool. :)

Comment: Interesting tool, upvoted. Can the step 2 and 3 automated in a "setup" script?

Comment: I don’t know about the general case, but under NPM/yarn/etc the way I do that is using Husky and Lint-Staged. Documentation for doing so is on the site’s Readme, and the project also uses that same setup.