# Simplify Git procedure

Tags: git

I use Git to deploy my projects in my production system. The procedure I follow is:

- First time I clone the repository, make changes in the config file (different in any production server) and then create a branch called "pro" that keeps these changes. Production server is always working in "pro" branch.
- Then, when there are changes and I want to update my server I execute a batch file that makes this (more or less):

  ```
  git checkout master
  git pull
  git checkout pro
  git rebase master
  ```

I'm sure that git has a easier way to do this, but I don't know how (perhaps it's possible to update one branch from another). Is just for curiosity and learn more about Git.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should work (on `pro`)

```
git fetch --all
git rebase origin/master
```

However, I don't see any problem with a 4-liner ;)

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend a different method as it isn't generic to all environements (dev, UAT, prod, ...).

Why not using a **[content filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7661043/symfony-1-4-best-practice-production-development-configuration/7661365#7661365)** with:

- a versioned template config file
- several config values (included a '`prod_values`' file)
- a version script (called the '`smudge`' script) able to recognize its execution environment (prod or not prod) and generated the right (unversioned) final config file

[image: content filter driver]

You would push to a bare repo with a [`post-receive` hook checkout'ing your project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838727/git-post-receive-hook-for-website-staging) in the right production directory.

Since this project has a content filter declared in it, the `smudge` script will automatically (on checkout) create the right config file.

Comment: Just a small note - OP's procedure isn't rewriting `master`, just `pro`, which probably doesn't matter assuming that it's not public.

Comment: @Mark: right, I have fixed the main reason for using content filter.