# Git - Push to Deploy and Removing Dev Config

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, git, heroku

So I'm writing a Facebook App using Rails, and hosted on Heroku.

On Heroku, you deploy by pushing your repo to the server.

When I do this, I'd like it to automatically change a few dev settings (facebook secret, for example) to production settings.

What's the best way to do this? Git hook?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of common practices to handle this situation if you don't want to use Git hooks or other methods to modify the actual code upon deploy.

**Environment Based Configuration**

If you don't mind having the production values your configuration settings in your repository, you can make them environment based. I sometimes use something like this:

```
# config/application.yml

default:
  facebook:
    app_id: app_id_for_dev_and_test
    app_secret: app_secret_for_dev_and_test
    api_key: api_key_for_dev_and_test

production:
  facebook:
    app_id: app_id_for_production
    app_secret: app_secret_for_production
    api_key: api_key_for_production

# config/initializers/app_config.rb

require 'yaml'

yaml_data = YAML::load(ERB.new(IO.read(File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'application.yml'))).result)

config = yaml_data["default"]
begin
  config.merge! yaml_data[Rails.env]
rescue TypeError
  # nothing specified for this environment; do nothing
end

APP_CONFIG = HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(config)
```

Now you can access the data via, for instance, `APP_CONFIG[:facebook][:app_id]`, and the value will automatically be different based on which environment the application was booted in.

**Environment Variables Based Configuration**

Another option is to specify production data via environment variables. Heroku allows you to do this via [config vars](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars).

1. Set up your code to use a value based on the environment (maybe with optional defaults):

   ```
   facebook_app_id = ENV['FB_APP_ID'] || 'some default value'
   ```
2. Create the production config var on Heroku by typing on a console:

   ```
   heroku config:add FB_APP_ID=the_fb_app_id_to_use
   ```

Now `ENV['FB_APP_ID']` is `the_fb_app_id_to_use` on production (Heroku), and `'some default value'` in development and test.

The Heroku documentation linked above has some more detailed information on this strategy.

Comment: For now, this is the solution that I've gone with. It works great. Thank-you. Also, the description of HashWithIndifferentAccess is hilarious, if you haven't seen it: http://as.rubyonrails.org/classes/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html

Answer (score 0):

You can explore the idea of a **[content filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7661043/symfony-1-4-best-practice-production-development-configuration/7661365#7661365)**, based on a **'`smudge`' script executed automatically on checkout**.

[image: content filter]

You would declare:

- some (versioned) *template* files
- some value files
- a (versioned) `smudge` script able to recognize its execution environment and generate the necessary (non-versioned) final files from the value files or (for more sensitive information) from other sources external to the Git repo.