# working with Git - Multiple environments with different configs

Tags: git, workflow, gitlab

This is a general question about working with `Git`. I have a git server running `GitLab`, I have a progect there and that project has 3 stages (Just like any project) Local->Testing->Production. Each environment has a different global & database config files. How do commit/pull/push/etc... without overwriting these files?

Furthermore, I tried creating a branch for my local development. I ran `git rm --cached` on each of the config files and when I merged with my master it deleted them.

I think I am missing something about working with `Git`.

Is there something like "protected files" or something like that so I can set specific files not to sync to master?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7287324/6309 could help

Comment: perhaps also http://stackoverflow.com/q/20078756/1290731