# Can .gitignore files be named ? (e.g. xxx.gitignore)

Tags: git, github, gitignore

I would like to know whether it is possible to have **named** `.gitignore` files in a repository, such as:

```
Composer.gitignore
Node.gitignore
```

Both of the above examples are shown available in GitHub's [gitignore template repository](https://github.com/github/gitignore) (perhaps this might be a bit misleading).

I have tried adding `Composer.gitignore` to my repository and it seems like the file is not read (I'm using SourceTree).

**EDIT:**

Adding relevant information added by [Boldewyn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/113195/boldewyn) that does not directly answer the question:

> > The page's README says:
> >
> > A Collection of `.gitignore` templates
> >     and that's what it is: Only templates. If you want to use one, pick it, drop it in your repository and rename it to `.gitignore`.
> >
> > git recognizes only two places for listing ignored files: `.gitignore` files in a folder/subfolder and the file `.git/info/ignore`. See [`git help gitignore`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitignore.html) for in-depth information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only way you could make a file *not* name .gitignore as a .gitignore file is:

- reference it directly

  ```
  git config --global core.excludesfile ~/myfile.gitignore
  ```
- generate it through a [`smudge` script from a content filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7005830/6309).
  That second option is a bit convoluted, but would process all versionned `<file>.gitignore` and generate the final `.gitignore`.

Other than those two options, the [`.gitignore` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) doesn't allow any other naming convention.

Comment: Oooohhh! That smudge filter thing is a piece of true genial evilness! +1

Answer (score 5):

The page's README says:

> A Collection of `.gitignore` templates

and that's what it is: Only templates. If you want to use one, pick it, drop it in your repository and rename it to `.gitignore`.

`git` recognizes only two places for listing ignored files: `.gitignore` files in a folder/subfolder and the file `.git/info/ignore`. See [`git help gitignore`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitignore.html) for in-depth information.

Comment: I will copy your answer as an edit to my Question, as even though it does not directly answer my question it adds very important information.