# How to include files in .gcloudignore that are ignored in .gitignore

Tags: git, github, google-cloud-platform, gitignore, gcloud

I have certain folders that I ignore in my `.gitignore` as I do not want it to be published on Github.

However, these files are essential for when deploying to Google Cloud (local packages).

If I take out `.gitignore` from `.gcloudignore` then the files that I do want to ignore (like `venv, .idea, .pyc`) are uploaded, which is what I do not want.

How can I there include only a portion of `.gitgnore` in `.gcloudignore`?

---

**.gcloudignore**

```
.gcloudignore
.git
.gitignore

node_modules
#!include:.gitignore
```

**.gitignore**

```
# This I want to ignore in .gcloudignore
.Python
env/
build/

# This I want to keep in .gcloudignore
module_data_import
module_calendar
```

Comment: I just created the `.gcloudignore` file and it fixed my problem

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The 2 files are mostly orthogonal, they serve different purposes and are used by different tools.

The only relationship between them (apart from `.gcloudignore` inheriting heavily from the `.gitignore` syntax and behaviour) is the ability to include the `.gitignore` file inside the `.gcloudignore` file, which is what you do with:

```
#!include:.gitignore
```

The side effect of that is, of course, that *everything* in `.gitignore` will also be ignored during GAE deployments, as you observed. From [gcloud topic gcloudignore](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/gcloudignore):

> This will include the contents of a `.gitignore`-style file at that
>   path at that point in the file. It does not recurse (that is, the
>   included file `cannot` `#!include` another file) and cannot be
>   anywhere but the top-level directory to be uploaded.

But you **don't have to** include `.gitignore`. All you need to do is drop that inclusion and specify exactly just the patterns from `.gitignore` that you want to ignore in deployments. If I understand correctly your goal description the `.gcloudignore` would look something like this:

```
.gcloudignore
.git
.gitignore

node_modules
module_data_import
module_calendar
```

If duplicating those patterns in both files bothers you a potential alternative (IMHO rather complex) *might* be to take advantage of git's ability to ignore files based on patterns collected from multiple sources (with different scopes, though, so pay attention to that). See  https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore and [Can I include other .gitignore file in a .gitignore file? (like #include in c-like languages)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005142/can-i-include-other-gitignore-file-in-a-gitignore-file-like-include-in-c-li).

If you can find a proper split fitting your application you could:

- keep in `.gitignore` just the patterns for files that you also want to ignore at deployments (keeping, of course, the `.gitignore` inclusion in `.gcloudignore`)
- place the other patterns in another file that git uses to determine ignore rules - thus they'd be ignored by git but since this file isn't included in `.gcloudignore`  they would not be ignored at deployments.

UPDATE following comment:

In the initial answer I didn't consider the case in which the gcloud command itself executes operations that target directly or indirectly source code repository operations under the hood which, if using git as the version control system, will be, of course, impacted by the presence and content of the .gitignore file. In such case one could arguably consider that the gcloud command itself uses the .gitignore file (regardless of the .gcloudignore file).

Comment: >> The 2 files are mostly orthogonal, they serve different purposes and are used by different tools.
Wrong. The 'gcloud builds' command ingores stuff in .gitignore.

Comment: You mean without it being included in .gcloudignore? If so I bet it's not intended ;)

Comment: You can demonstrate that it does use gitignore and that it is intended. Follow the Cloud Build Quickstart at https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/quickstart-docker  Add a .gitignore file containing the single line 
quickstart.sh 
After executing the cloud build command you will get the output   
Check the gcloud log... (see `$ gcloud topic gcloudignore` to learn
more). ...
Step 2/3 : COPY quickstart.sh /
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder267017000/quickstart.sh: no such file or directory
ERROR

Comment: That's not what the document says (which would, indeed, demonstrate intention). It may be indeed the description of the symptoms you observe, but that doesn't demonstrate intent, it could be accidental.

Comment: @alexamies I updated my answer. The gcloud build is uploading the source code from your current directory for the cloud build which will be executed remotely. I suspect git is used under the hood to manage the source code as a repo. By adding that.gitignore file you prevent uploading an essential piece for the build.

Comment: Nice. Thanks. Besides GAE, I saw the same thing with Cloud Run.

Comment: It's probably not intentional. This is a problem for me; I hope Google will fix it soon...

Answer (score 27):

You can explicitly include a file if it has already been excluded by a pattern (such as inheriting your .gitignore settings, or an excluded directory) previously in the .gcloudignore file.

To include a file named `foo`, make sure the following comes after the rule that excluded it:

```
!foo
```

To include a folder named 'bar', make sure the following comes after the rule that excluded it:

```
!bar/
```

Source: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/gcloudignore

Comment: What about a folder

Comment: Updated my answer with an example for directories.

Answer (score 1):

To include a folder that is ignored in `.gitignore` I had to use the following syntax:

```
!bar/**
```

Without `**` is was not working.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to have what is in `.gitignore` with one exception. This has worked for me:

```
#!include:.gitignore

!foo
```