# Cloud Build Docker not building

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I am trying to build an image using google cloud build for my GKE. Locally I can build images using this command:

```
docker build -t backend .
docker  tag backend  gcr.io/project-id/backend:v15.8
docker  push  gcr.io/project-id/backend:v15.8
```

And it works fine but when I am trying to use:

```
steps:
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker"
  args: ["build", "-t", "gcr.io/project-id/backend:v15.8", "."]
  # push container image
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker"
  args: ["push", "gcr.io/project-id/backend:v15.8"]
```

This code is building the image but I don't know why some of the files it misses. I have several files in .gitignore.

I can build an image but it is not the same as I am building an image from command locally. When I am deploying it to my GKE one file is missing which is in .gitignore file. What do I need to do in order to achieve my goal

Comment: What is the missing file? Perhaps a credential file?

Comment: I am using Django and I added my settings.py in my .gitignore When I am building an image using local commands it works great but. Using cloud build I am getting error settings.py not there. I am running cloud build inside my project directory

Comment: Use a `.gcloudignore` file. Ignore the `.gitignore` and specify the Cloud Build files to ignore. This answer might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56963506/8016720

Comment: I added the #!include:.gitignore to my  .gcloudignore  no change is there any way we can delete the cache.

Comment: From what I understood of what the issue is and what John shared above, plus what is mentioned on the answer shared, you should only use a `.gcloudignore` and specify in there the files you want to ignore instead of importing the `.gitignore` into the `.gcloudignore`. Did you try that?

Comment: I don't want to ignore anything my cloud build is ignoring when I am running the code. And in my .gitignore my settings.py is ignored and I want that file when I build the image. Is cloud build using git ignore to build my image if yes then how to add that file?

Comment: if you want to add a file that is being ignored by `.gitignore` you **should not** import the `.gitignore` into the `.gcloudignore`, instead of that you should specify manually all the files that are in the `.gitignore` and that you also want in `.gcloudignore`.

Comment: I added this line .gitignore to .gcloudignore meaning I ignored the ignore file as suggested by @JohnHanley and it worked. GCP should provide the proper documents.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @JohnHanley on the comments, the use of `.gcloudignore` is recommended in cases like this. You should ignore the `.gitignore` file inside the `.gcloudignore` to be able to use the required file.

So if you add this a line with `.gitignore` to your `.gcloudignore` it will fix the issue you are facing.