# Is there a command to "roll up" a tree of gitignores into one parent gitignore?

Tags: git, gitignore

Over time this large project has acquired quite a few .gitignore files scattered across its many directories. Adding a new .gitignore "at the site" is very handy when you're dealing with some new output folder or something, but it becomes hard to reason about.

**Is there a way to "roll up" all these disparate .gitignore files back into the .gitignore at the root of the project?** The end result would be a single .gitignore project-wide, with all the other ad-hoc ones removed.

It would be extra special if I could roll up one subtree at a time, or to a common child, so that I can manage the changes a little bit more effectively, but I won't be choosy.

---

**Concrete example:**

Before:

```
root
|- .gitignore
|- subdir1
|  |- .gitignore
|  |- subdir3
|     |- .gitignore
|     |- ignored_file.txt
|- subdir2
   |- .gitignore
```

```
# the .gitignore in subdir3
/ignored_file.txt
```

After:

```
root
|- .gitignore
|- subdir1
|  |- subdir3
|     |- ignored_file.txt
|- subdir2
```

```
# the .gitignore in root
/subdir1/subdir3/ignored_file.txt
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: You could write a ruby script or similar.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I include other .gitignore file in a .gitignore file? (like #include in c-like languages)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005142/can-i-include-other-gitignore-file-in-a-gitignore-file-like-include-in-c-li)

Comment: @TheGeorgeous Thanks, but not quite, my goal is to specifically clean up all the misc. .gitignores lying around and have only a single one remain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard linux `find` command (or its more recent sibling `fd`) will list the files for you :

```sh
$ find * -name .gitignore
.gitignore
subdir1/.gitignore
subdir1/subdir3/.gitignore
subdir2/.gitignore
```

If you have a script that expands a `.gitignore` file :

```sh
# write a script, which takes a path as input,
# and prefixes all patterns found within the file with 'path/' :
$ expand.py subdir1/subdir3/.gitignore
/subdir1/subdir3/ignored_file.txt
```

You can combine both :

```sh
$ find * -name .gitignore | xargs -L1 expand.py
# look only in the subdir1 subdirectory :
$ find subdir1/ -name .gitignore | xargs -L1 expand.py
```

Comment: Thanks! I had started going down this path but your explanation here looks much simpler and more reliable than what I was attempting.