# How do I merge selected changes in a Git branch?

Tags: git, merge, conflict

I have two branches for development and deployment. I made committed some changes to the deployment branch which I wanted to merge into the development branch. Now I expected the merge command to show a conflict in such cases -

```
//development
$path = 'localhost';
```

and

```
//deployment
$path = 'example.com';
```

Instead what happens is that the deployment branch line just replaces the development branch line. I can cherry pick the commits and apply them to the development branch or make the changes manually but I thought there must be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

It will only conflict if you had of *changed* it in the development branch as well. So because you only changed it in Deployment its just a normal version change.

Simply don't commit that particular file in your changeset. (assuming that you made no other changes in that file)

Comment: Yes, I didn't change it in the original. In this particular case there are other minor changes in the file, it would be nice if there was a way to avoid doing manual edits as it is possible for configuration files to vary a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Since that configuration file varies a lot, it is best to completely avoid any merge issue for this type of file.

You should versions the values of that config file in separate files:

- `config_dev.values`
- `config_depl.values`

And you would have only one versioned `config.template` file with placeholder for the values:

```
// server name for dev or deployment or other environments
$path = '@@SERVER_NAME@@'
```

That way, this template file doesn't change and won't be merged.
You would also version a script able to, on checkout, generate the actual config file (which wouldn't be versioned, remaining "private", ie only local to your current working directory)

[image: content filter driver]

If you declare that script as a **[content filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316677/can-git-automatically-switch-between-spaces-and-tabs/2316728#2316728)** in a `.gitattributes` file, it will be executed automatically on `git checkout`, and will look for a file it recognizes as your config.template file (the script isn't pass any file name or file path, it [only gets the content of each checked-out files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059326/git-equivalent-of-subversions-url-keyword-expansion/2059393#2059393))