# Same change keeps reappearing after checkout

Tags: git, changeset

Git keeps adding the same changeset, which looks like this:

```
@@ -1,12 +1,12 @@
-<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
-<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
-    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
-    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
-    android:orientation="vertical" >
-
-    <TextView
-        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
-        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
-       android:text="@string/hello" />
-
+<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
+<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
+    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
+    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
+    android:orientation="vertical" >
+
+    <TextView
+        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
+        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
+        android:text="@string/hello" />
+
 </LinearLayout>
\ No newline at end of file
```

The file is not open in any editor, and every time I discard changes by doing a `git checkout`or by using the github tool, the changes reappear without me even doing anything. Committing the files changes nothing, the same changeset reappears immediately.

How do I keep it from doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whole file is always changed? **Line endings!** (read it as [**LINE ENDINGS**](http://youtu.be/Alw5hs0chj0)!!!)

You can read [git's manual](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#Formatting-and-Whitespace) on [line ending conversion](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_end-of-line_conversion), Github also as a [nice detailed explanation](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings) on this, but to put it basically:

- Your editor should use expected line endings (most people stick with the OS default)
- Your core.autocrlf in gitconfig should follow the editor's option.

You might need to issue a commit fixing the line issue if you made a commit with the wrong line ending (i.e. the git repo should always be in LF).

Comment: And it is also only with these files, not any other

Comment: @TheGuyOfDoom, are you sure there's [nothing interested being executed via `.gitattributes`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2059393/720999)?

Comment: well, gitattributes was empty. It turned out it had to do with the crlf stuff though, but core.autocrlf was not enough to fix it. I made a whole bunch of changes but eventually ended up with a lf only repo and lost the conflicts.

Comment: I could ninja edit to mention the following: you don't need to edit the file to get a bad checkout, only have a bad repo!

E.g.: If you move a repo between OSes you can get this problem.