# Why it does not allow to change the default rebase activity?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

We are working in multisite UCM environment.

In while my colleague was trying to rebase stream and he was prevented from doing it as there was already a delivery was pending in that stream.

Now in his view that rebase activity is set by default.

After the delivery is accepted in master replica, some one else has rebased the same stream.

Now my colleague is not allowed to rebase as the stream is update. But while we were trying to change the default activity from view properties , it doesn't allow and saying that rebase in progress.

Will it automatically corrected after synchronizaztion? or it will be keep on occuring , why it occurs and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are dealing with snapshot view, the first thing to do is a full update (from the root directory of the view)

You also need to check the rebase status of the Stream you are (and on the right site depending on where the rebase was actually started, in order to take into account the multisite aspect).

```
cleartool rebase -status -stream yourStream@\YourPVob
```

As long as that status says a rebase is in progress, [it needs to be completed](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.hlp.doc/cc_main/to_complete_rebase.htm) (especially if it was in its "complete" phase: cancelling a rebase can fail for a variety of reason: see [technote 2059393](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059326/git-equivalent-of-subversions-url-keyword-expansion/2059393#2059393)).
That status will mention the name of the view currently affected by said rebase.