# Is the "assume-unchanged" information committed?

Tags: git, gitignore

There is a certain file that I want to share in its current state, but I don't want further changes to be committed.   So I did "assume-unchanged" to that file. Now, git ignores changes to this file in my repository. But what about other users of the repository - will they have to do "assume-unchanged" for this file in their own repository?

Is there a way to automatically make the "assume-unchanged" directive valid for other users too, as it is done with the "gitignore" information?

Comment: Think about it: when you mark a file as assume-unchanged, and then run `git commit`, does it let you commit, or does it tell you there is nothing to commit? (It's the latter.) If you cannot commit, how can you get the assume-unchanged information to others?

Comment: It could be commited just like the ignore information - through a file such as ".gitignore".

Comment: Yes, it could be, but it isn't, and it's easily verified that it isn't. Don't get me wrong, it's a perfectly reasonable question to ask yourself, but it's a question to which you should be able to find the answer rather quickly just by trying.

Comment: Yes, I saw that nothing is committed, but I thought that maybe I was doing something wrong... I can never be sure.

Comment: Now that could be a far more interesting question. :) If you *want*  to make sure other users of the repository get the same `assume-unchanged` settings, how would you do it? (Personally, I'd try to rework the project so that there's no need for it, and if that's not possible, I'd include a script in the project to set it up that other users can run if they so choose.)

Comment: I have edited my answer with an alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, [`git update-index --assume-unchanged`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index) only updates the index of your local repo.

Not the index of any other remote repo, and this is not pushed.
that would be [the same for `git update-index --skip-worktree`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23806990/6309)

One approach which can be pushed around is using a content filter driver, in order to generate the actual file from a versioned template.
See for instance "[Automatically ignore selected code changes when pushing to a git-hub repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11915604/6309)"

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/77Oy5.png]

<sup>(image from "[Customizing Git Attributes](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Keyword-Expansion)" from the [Git Book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/))</sup>