# gitignore loads other gitignores

Tags: git, gitignore

Is it possible? The `git update-index --assume-unchanged` is no solution, ignored files have to be tracked. Creating submodules either.

E.g.

*cat .customgitignore(1|2|3...)*

```
i-do-not-need-this.extension
```

*cat .gitignore*

```
basic-stuff.extension
<load> .customgitignore1
<load> .customgitignore2
<load> .customgitignore3
 etc
```

Issue description for those interested.

I am creating private repo of configs. One branch = one config. Additional branch as workspace. I merge other branches-configs with workspace depending on requirements. Branches-configs each have their own .gitignore which should be applied only after merge. I am trying to omit conflicts in gitignore file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I am trying to omit conflicts in gitignore file

Then don't version the final .gitignore file itself: generate it on demand.

Keep your .gitignore files separates, but add a [content filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2316728/6309) (a `smudge` script), which will:

- [detect the content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059326/git-equivalent-of-subversions-url-keyword-expansion/2059393#2059393) of each .gitignore.xxx files
- concatenate their content to the actual .gitignore (which is not added to git, and remains a private file)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As Git doesn't support this out of the box, you may implement one yourself with Git hooks, for example:

In any case, you will need to manage your ignores and includes in a custom file, not a `.gitignore` itself, as this one will be generated. So, let's say, you have a `.gitignoreincludes` file in a branch, and custom include files in other branches.

So, you may install a "post-merge" hook like this, for example:

```
#!/bin/bash
gitignoreWithIncludes=".gitignoreincludes"    
if [[ -f $gitignoreWithIncludes ]]; then
  echo ".gitignore" > .gitignore
  while read -r line
  do
      if [[ $line == include* ]]; then
        includeName=${line:8}
        while read -r includeLine
        do
          echo $includeLine >> .gitignore
        done < $includeName
      else
        echo $line >> .gitignore
      fi
  done < $gitignoreWithIncludes 
fi
```

This hook will launch on any *successful* merge, will look for a `.gitignoreincludes` file, and, if it exists, will generate a `.gitignore` file. `.gitignore` will contain all entries from `.gitignoreincludes` and all entries from all files referenced as `include FILE_NAME`. Having `.gitignore` ignoring itself allows it to be safely regenerated multiple times when doing merges.

This can be further improved by allowing `include` instructions in included files as well, or also a `post-checkout` hook can be implemented to regenerate the .gitignore when switching between branches, etc., etc..