# Reference multiple online gitignore templates in gitignore

Tags: git, github, gitignore, package-managers

For my global gitignore, I would like multiple up-to-date gitignore templates from https://github.com/github/gitignore for my OS / IDEs / languages / frameworks like [macOS](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/macOS.gitignore), [Java](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Java.gitignore), [Android](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Android.gitignore), and [JetBrains](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/JetBrains.gitignore).

There are some solutions here to concatenate locally:

[Can I include other .gitignore file in a .gitignore file? (like #include in c-like languages)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005142/can-i-include-other-gitignore-file-in-a-gitignore-file-like-include-in-c-li)

[gitignore loads other gitignores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18750179/gitignore-loads-other-gitignores)

but I'm wondering if there are more elegant solutions that simply concatenate the up-to-date templates from the specified urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore

# concatenating URLs
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/github/gitignore/master/Python.gitignore https://raw.githubusercontent.com/github/gitignore/master/Global/macOS.gitignore > ~/.gitignore

# alternative pre-concatenated .gitignore service
curl -sL https://www.gitignore.io/api/c,c++ > ~/.gitignore
```

Lines like this in my `.bashrc` file run every time I launch my shell and overwrite my global `.gitignore` file with the latest versions of the `.gitignore`'s from that repository

Answer (score 2):

The [content filter driver that you reference (and that I wrote)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7005830/6309) is done automatically on checkout.

That script can do anything you want, including fetching the latest version of those remote gitignore file (through a simple curl for instance), and generate the updated concatenated file.

Answer (score 1):

I run the a project that hosts the largest amount of gitignore templates and it's extremely easy to use.

- You can use the web to generate a template at https://gitignore.io
- You can install gitignore [via command line](https://www.gitignore.io/docs#-install-command-line-linux) to type

  ```
  gi java,macos,android,jetbrains
  ```

  output: https://www.gitignore.io/api/java,macos,android,jetbrains
- You can also update your existing templates using this url:
  https://www.gitignore.io/?templates=java,macos,android,jetbrains
- And finally, you can contribute to the list of templates which merges [@github/gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore) and over 100 other community templates to create the largest repository of templates at: https://github.com/dvcs/gitignore