# How to make git fill tags? keywords?

Tags: git, version-control

In my sourcecode I would put tags like the following and SVN would fill in the lastchangedate, author, revision etc..  Can this be done with git?  Can someone please tell me how.. thanks

```
/**
* Last changed: $LastChangedDate$
* @author $Author$
* @version $Revision$
*
*/
```

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11534655/git-keyword-substitution-like-those-in-subversion

Comment: I wrote a shell script that will do this for you, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17242693/1775715 Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

"clean" and "smudge" filters - ["Keyword Expansion"](http://git-scm.com/book/ch7-2.html#Keyword-Expansion) section

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that git has this.  But you would be able to write a hook to run and perform the operation that you are thinking.

http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks