# Git keywords for code templates

Tags: eclipse, git

Does Git have keywords to use in code templates with Eclipse? 
I mean keywords as with svn.
Something like $revision, $lastchangedby etc...

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no Keyworkd on Git(https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#Does_Git_have_keyword_expansion.3F),
 But, you can implement that with script. ([Git keyword substitution like those in Subversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11534655/git-keyword-substitution-like-those-in-subversion))