# Get $id equilvalent on git with eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, pydev, egit

I am writing some scripts and sending them to some friends, etc...

When i used SVN, i used to put the  $Id tag on the file (pupulated by Eclipse) so i could clearly identify the file.

However, I can't find a similar way to do it with egit/eclipse.

Any recommendation/help/suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, Git doesn't have a keyword substitution mechanism:
See "[Does git have anything like `svn propset svn:keywords` or pre-/post-commit hooks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39742/does-git-have-anything-like-svn-propset-svnkeywords-or-pre-post-commit-hooks)"

"[Moving from CVS to git: `$Id:$` equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384108/moving-from-cvs-to-git-id-equivalent)" explains that **[`git describe`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe)** is the prefered way to reference not just a file version, but the whole repo commit (which includes that specific file version)

However, when looking at [JGit](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit) (used by Egit), I don't see any '`describe`' class.
So it might not be supported directly by EGit.

Comment: Not exaclty the answer that i was look for :( ! Thanks