# Git Svn getting autoprops like $Date$ , $Author$, $Revision$

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

In our Svn repo, Some auto props defined for sql files;
I'm commiting sql like like this to svn repo.

```
$Rev$
$Date$
$Author$
```

After commit, When I checked the file I see this variables replaced with values regarding revision,commit date and the author.

```
$Rev: xxxxxx $
$Date: 2023-04-10 11:11:11 -0200 (Mon, 10 Apr 2023) $
$Author: yyyyy zzzzz $
```

I have also git svn folder for side project. When I download same revision from svn, I got file like in the first paragraph;

```
$Rev$
$Date$
$Author$
```

Is there any setting that I need to set up for reading and replacing auto props in git svn, or it's defect that git svn has?

I want to get same output whatever svn itself is getting.

```
$Rev: xxxxxx $
$Date: 2023-04-10 11:11:11 -0200 (Mon, 10 Apr 2023) $
$Author: yyyyy zzzzz $
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62264/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/39742/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/2059326/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-svn%5D+keywords

Comment: BTW those are not properties, they're called "keywords".